# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI stringByDeletingPathExtension]:

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am using `UIPageViewController` and set content viewController of it , i know the error msg saying  some how `stringByDeletingPathExtension` called which is not method of the object.  My initialViewControllers is working fine

```
  NSArray *viewControllers =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:initialViewController, initialViewController1,nil ];

 giving exception on this line   ----->    [_pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers
                                 direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                  animated:NO
                                completion:nil];
```

Comment: Somewhere, there is a wrong class of an object: a `NSArray` object trying to do a `NSString` method. That's why says the error (if I guess, there is a "unrecognized selector" in the error message. I'd suggest to check the objects class. You don't have to call explicitly the method of the reason in your code, they may be "hidden" call (like inside another method check that you don't see). So check the class of `_pageViewController`, `viewControllers`, `initialViewController` and `initialViewController1`.

Comment: Is your problem solved? What was your issue?

Comment: yes problem Solved ..

Comment: Please share your correction, in order to help someone who could have the same issue in the future.